# coverting hover jquery code into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help converting a Jquery code into a javascript code where it changes the border radius of a div when hovering over it.

```
HTML
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="SampleQ3.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h4>Pasta</h4>
        </div>
        <script src="SampleJavaScript.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
   


JS
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div").hover(function () {
            $(this).css("border-radius", "0%");
    
        }, function () {
            $(this).css("border-radius", "200px 200px 200px 200px");
        });
    });
```

Comment: jQuery is already in Javascript code, I guess what you ask is to have the equivalent in DOM.

Comment: Still new to this not sure what DOM means, basically just want to know how to convert the java code into jquery or vice-versa.

Comment: you can do this only using css.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of that only using css, but I will provide both solution js and css.

javascript code:

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(div of divs) {
   div.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
       event.target.style.borderRadius = 0%;
   }, false);

   div.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
       event.target.style.borderRadius = '200px';
   }, false);

}
```

To do the same with css you can add a class to make it easer to target.

```
// css 
<style>
.div-round {
    border-radius: 200px;
}

.div-round:hover {
  border-radius: 0%;
}

</style>

//add class to div
<div class='div-round'>...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the css part you did, is there a way so we dont edit css and make it so javascript adds the border-radius 0% to the div hover section without touching css?

Comment: These are two ways that I would do it, they are separated ways. @helpme7

Comment: From [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/): `The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.` ... shorthand for `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`. Which is what this javascript code is doing. Although for something simple like this, I would recommend the css option. And also you could simplify `0%` to just `0`.